# is device iPhone or iPad programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am developing global application (iPhone and iPad). I am doing different process for iPhone or iPad. But I saw crash like below screen shot. This crash device is iPhone but have run the code I wrote for iPad. How could this be. I wrote code that distinguishes the iPhone and iPad is faulty? thanx

[image]

```
   -(IBAction)showSearchAirports:(id)sender{

        UIButton *tempButton=(UIButton*)sender;

        AirportSearch2 *airportsSearch=[[AirportSearch2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"AirportSearch" bundle:nil];

        if ([self isDeviceiPhone]) {
            [self presentViewController:airportsSearch animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }else{


                if (self.popOver) {
                    [self.popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
                    self.popOver = nil;

                }

                UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:airportsSearch] autorelease];


                self.popOver=[[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController] autorelease];

                self.popOver.delegate                    = self;
                [self.popOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(285, 370)];

                //This line 481
                [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:tempButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];


        }

}



-(BOOL)isDeviceiPhone{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        return  TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code you use to determine device type :)

Comment: Actually There is In continuation of the code

Comment: App was crashed at `[self presentViewController:airportsSearch animated:YES completion:NULL];` line. Your condition is correct

Comment: @aoneki Whoops.Sorry I missed seeing your isDeviceiPhone method earlier. Can you try switching your if block to use the Apple defined macro that a number of us suggested below.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
         // The device is an iPad running iOS 3.2 or later.
         Return NO;
    }
    else
    {
         // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
         Return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect device type use following methods :

```
+ (BOOL) isiPad {
#if (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200)
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector: @selector(userInterfaceIdiom)])
        return ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#endif
    return NO;
}


+(BOOL)isiPhone
{
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this Macro Defined in UIdevice Class you can refer to documentation  (https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)  also 
just simply use condition like

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    return yes;
}
else
    return No;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the code you use to determine the type of device, but here's one way you can determine device type at runtime.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    // iPad-specific interface here
}
else
{
    // iPhone and iPod touch interface here
}
```